# Access violation exception with oracle 12c ODP.NET 64bit

Tags: oracle, access-violation, odp.net, oracle12c, oracle-aq

We are using Oracle 12c 64 bit ODP.NET client to work with AQ on an Oracle 12c database. We have been able to connect and work with the database, but have experienced occasional data corruption and access violation exceptions (AVE) when dequeuing messages. The AVE terminates our application in a bad way.

We are connecting from a machine running Windows Server R2 2012 standard 64 bit. The IDE is Visual Studio Professional 2015.

I would really appreciate some help on this issue. We are going to try a couple of things like using the 32 bit client

```
Application: DC.Receiver.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsAQ.FreeObject(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleAQQueue.Dequeue(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleAQDequeueOptions)
       ...
```

From the event log:

```
Faulting application name: DC.Receiver.exe, version: 1.2.11.0, time stamp: 0x57f4c681
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18202, time stamp: 0x569e7eb1
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
Faulting process id: 0x4444
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2207bb78cf393
Faulting application path: C:\From\DC.Receiver\bin\DC.Receiver.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: f817dfa6-8c6e-11e6-80c9-00155d3a3a0a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Anything in the alert logs or trace files?

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix ?